# How open file in PhpStorm by clicking on backtrace line on error page in browser

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

When occurs error in code, browser displays error page with backtrace:

[image]

Is it possible to open file in PhpStorm by clicking on line with error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use next approach: copy two files [from this project](https://github.com/mnvx/laravel-ide-code-navigation) into your Laravel project:

- `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` (override ExceptionHandler::render() to call modified view of error page)
- `resources/views/errors/error.blade.php` (modified view of error page)

So, your error page will looks like:
[image]

When you click on "Go to line" link, file with this line opens in PhpStorm.